# I Cannot Connect to my NAS

Tags: networking, tcp

Our home network consists of two laptops, two tablets, two mobile phones, a printer and a NAS for backups. All running off a wireless router that provides the IP addresses.

Suddenly, about three days ago, I can no longer connect to the NAS. The message I get says "Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found." This happens on my laptop only; my wife's laptop doesn't have a problem. I've also checked and the printer works from my laptop.

The probable cause (but unproven) was when I made some changes to protect me from the Wannacry ransomware. I received messages from both Malwarebytes and Avast telling me to do the same thing. That was to go into the advanced settings of Windows Firewall and add two inbound rules. I don't remember the exact details but one rule affected TCP and one affected UDP (I'm somewhat out of my depth here.)

It was after this that I first saw the problem, so first I disabled the rules and then deleted them, but that made no difference. I've tried switching off Windows Firewall but that makes no difference either. I've researched the problem via Google and found some advice to reset TCP/IP settings. I did that via the command prompt, but that didn't work either.

Any other suggestions that don't involve a hard re-install or throwing the whole damn thing out the window?

Answer (score 0):

> "error code 0x80070035 network path was not found"

it can be on Windows Vista and Windows 7 Computers. 
You can solve your problem like this:

"START" > "CONTROL PANEL" > "DEVICE MANAGER" > "NETWORK ADAPTERS"

Then click on "VIEW", and select "SHOW HIDDEN DEVICES".
In the expanded view you will see a long list of numbered "MICROSOFT 6to4 ADAPTER". Right click "DELETE" on all but 1 of them. When you have only 1 left, restart computer.

Answer (score 0):

> "error code 0x80070035 network path was not found"

I had the same error with several PCs in my network. I could not open shared folders of these PCs with the computer name. It was ok when I write the IP address.

Finally I just deselected TCP/IPv6 checkbox on the connection properties and its all ok.